# jdk-13.0.2 is not visible to the computer because of logisim

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, cmd, logic

I had to install logisim ( a logic circuit editor) but java 5 or any newer edition was required to do so, while i also had downloaded jdk-13.0.2 in order to develop some java projects .I was given this link in order to download logisim:
http://www.cburch.com/logisim/download.html

Also, i downloaded java 8 from the following link:

https://java.com/en/download/manual.jsp?fbclid=IwAR2BoP89O7qYdbWc0Knk5tSSvymVDN-5XF9FdAKo-_OT4pLnnAG-dcxlC9M

Although logisim was succesfully installed to my computer , java stopped working. In adittion vscode reports that no jdk is installed and that classpath system variable points to 0 .

Anyway, I found out that my jdk is stored where it should be ,which means in programm files , while i realised that i had downloaded two more jdks !!! (I still dont know how these got in my computer ...).But this shouldn't really matter because the cmd programm used everytime before starting coding in java still sets the classpath and path system variables at the correct destinations . 
The cmd  code is the following:

```
set path="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.2\bin"
set classpath=.;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.2\lib\tools.jar
```

(My point is that it doesn't seem to be the above program's fault. )
I also can't find the java edition (java 8) I was supposed to have already to downloaded in order to install and operate logisim with the file explorer.
I really need to keep both logisim and vscode operanotional.
Does it mean that im able to code in java just by having jdk ? ( I wouldn't bother to download java 8 if it wasn't for logisim...).

Also whenever I try to compile a java file using cmd , I get the following error back:

```
An error has occurred while processing the shared archive file.
Mark mismatch while restoring from shared file.
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Unable to use shared archive.
```

Any ideas could be helpful.

Comment: This is completely wrong, `set path="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.2\bin"`. You have removed everything from what is effectively a very important system variable. What you should be doing is adding it to the existing content, not overwriting it! Try `Set "PATH=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.2\bin;%PATH%"` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A new path system variable must be created for the new `JRE` installation also (the one installed for Logisim). Separate path variables should be there for `JDK` and new JRE.

For example:

For JDK- `D:\PROGRAM FILES\Java\jdk-15.0.2\bin`

For JRE- `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_281\bin`

Path system variable should point to the bin folder of wherever JRE installed.

Path system variables for JDK and JRE. SS from control panel:

[image]